# Detect pinch action on android with Processing

Tags: java, android, processing, zooming, pinchzoom

I am working on an android app that is written in Processing 3. It needs to be able to increase a variable when the pinch action "zoom in" is initiated, and decrease when "zoomed out".

**Is there a built-in way of doing this in Processing, and if not can someone give me a hint in the right direction to creating my own solution?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705923/how-to-detect-the-pinch-zoom-event-with-ongesturelistener-in-android

Comment: @PedroMazarini Thanks but I'm not sure how to implement this in Processing. Could you give me a nudge in the right direction about how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Ketai Library - KetaiGesture](http://ketai.org/reference/ui/ketaigesture/):

> Provides gesture recognition services to a processing sketch. To
> receive gesture events a sketch can define the following methods:
>
> ...
>
> onPinch(float x, float y, float r) - x,y of center, r is the distance

Example of code use to change the size of a circle using the Pinch motion:

```
import ketai.ui.*;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
 
float ellipseWidth = 50;
float ellipseHeight = 50;
KetaiGesture gesture;
 
void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
  gesture = new KetaiGesture(this);
}
 
void draw() {
  orientation(PORTRAIT);
  background(0);
  fill(0);
  stroke(255);
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, ellipseWidth, ellipseHeight);
}
 
void onPinch (float x, float y, float d) {
  ellipseWidth += d;
  ellipseHeight += d;
}

public boolean surfaceTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  //Call this to keep mouseX and mouseY updated
  super.surfaceTouchEvent(event);
 
  //Forward the event to the class for processing
  return gesture.surfaceTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering such a relatively old question! Unfortunately I'm on holiday for a bit and can't test it however I will try to remember when I get back.

Comment: @Jachdich no problem, let us know how you get on and whether it works for you!

Comment: @Jachdich has this answer at all resolved your problem?

Comment: sorry, I'm still away. As I'm on mobile data, I can't download the huge android SDK to try it out. Unfortunately it may be another 3/4 weeks before I can access my desktop (with Android SDK).